# Redirect empty URL subdomain to different directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have directories on my server such as:

```
mydomain.com/u/person1
mydomain.com/u/person2
mydomain.com/u/person3
etc...
```

Each of these directories has it's own username/password using .htaccess/htpasswd...

If someone tries to go to `mydomain.com/u[/]`, how can I get them to be forwarded to `mydomain.com/users` instead?

The reason for this is my domain is a no-index.html website; all the directories show Apache generated file trees (which I want). The `/u/` directory has 30+ password protected folders in it, and if anyone tries to go there, it tries to show a file tree of password protected directories and instantly bans the user from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in `/u/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /users/ [L,R=301]
```